# TimeoutExeption raised when using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeoutexception

I am using WebDriverWait in two different locations in my script, the syntax being the same every time; first time I use it just to see if I have a typo - this is defined under a class, and second time under a function, which is under the class. Here the error pops up, even though the syntax is the same. Please refer to the below code.

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.timeout).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                            '//div[starts-with(@class,"bill-summary-total")]//div[contains(@data-ng-bind-html,"vm.productList.totalAmt")]')))
        print('Your element is: {}'.format(element.text))


def pay(self):
    time.sleep(10)
    print('You are at this step')
    element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 7).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
    '//div[starts-with(@class,"bill-summary-total")]//div[contains(@data-ng-bind-html,"vm.productList.totalAmt")]')))
    print('Your element is: {}'.format(element.text))
```

In attached picture 1 works, 2- stops after step : `print('You are at this step').`

Error:
`raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Thank you in advance for your help.[image: TimeoutException]

Comment: You may want to include this in your question body rather than as a comment, 1) so that it can be formatted properly and 2) so that everything you have tried is listed together cohesively for people trying to answer your question. Separately, you haven't mentioned what the error/problem is with this new attempt?

Comment: using this:  def pay(self): time.sleep(10) self.timeout=7 print('You are at this step') element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.timeout).until(...etc, the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with the following code:

```
timeout = self.timeout
time.sleep(10)
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.timeout).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[starts-with(@class,"bill-summary-total")]//div[contains(@data-ng-bind-html,"vm.productList.totalAmt")]')))
print('Your element is: {}'.format(element.text))
```

Error was due to not having assigned self.timeout to a variable, in this case timeout, prior of using self.time later in the code.